# First and Last Child Border Radius not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following selectors on my menu to apply a border radius to the first and last child of my menu

```
.main-nav ul li a:first-child {border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px!important;}
.main-nav ul li a:last-child {border-radius:  0 6px 6px 0!important;}
```

I even tried the `!important` addition to try and force this on, however it is not working and I can't see where it would be overridden, can anyone please advise how to get round this?

[This the site.](http://www.pureelysium.com/PPTest/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your style sheet you have:

```
.main-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    background-color: #58585a; //remove this
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Remove the background-color line from .main-nav ul li. It's showing under your menu items so you can't see the border radius.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
.main-nav ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px!important;
}
.main-nav ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius:  0 6px 6px 0!important;
}
```

Comment: select everything below the first line and hit `ctrl-k` and save

Answer (score 0):

Styles are applied to `li` element not to `a` element

try this:

```
.main-nav ul li:first-child {border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px!important;}
.main-nav ul li:last-child {border-radius:  0 6px 6px 0!important;}
```

Comment: nope this doesnt appear to be working :( somethings overridding it somewhere and i have no idea where