# Border radius doesn't work in first-child pseudo class

Tags: html, css

I have paragraphs inside a div, and I want to add `border-bottom-left-radius` to the first `p` element inside the div, but it doesn't work:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</div>
```

The same happens with `:last-child`, `border-top-left-radius`, `border-top-right-radius`, `border-bottom-right-radius`.

What is the problem? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082674/first-and-last-child-border-radius-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003848/first-child-border-top-right-radius-wont-work) similar questions were fixed with the background, but I have none. Attempting to read [the specifications](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds/#propdef-border-bottom-right-radius) I found nothing related to the paragraph element or pseudo-class selectors.

Comment: `div :first-child`....

Comment: Typo: You will just need to a space after div before the colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents the first element among a group of sibling elements.

you need to apply it to the p element, not div element.

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
div p:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
</div>
```